# Sum data across the 5-year span

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Consider the following data:

```
  date  |  value  
--------+--------
 2004   |   1
 2005   |   2
 2006   |   3
 2007   |   4
 2008   |   5
 2009   |   6
```

I need to sum the values in the 5-year span, so the data would look like that:

```
  date  |  value  
--------+--------
 2005   |   3
 2010   |  18
```

How can I accomplish that? I am a beginer, so I do not even have a clue where to start.

Comment: you can begin with saying how you have read the data into variables, have you organized it in lists, are you using numpy or pandas, etc.

For example if you would use pandas, the only thing you need to do is read the docs of pandas, both for getting the data into memory and also how to do the sum over 5 years.

Look at docs for rolling average as example.

Comment: In general SO is not a good place for basic questions like this. There are plenty of tutorials and examples around on the net that will guide you on these basic things, assuming you are willing to spend some minutes to find out what the right search terms are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach with pd.cut:

```
years = pd.cut(
    df['date'], bins=np.arange(1900, 2100, 5)  # You can play with these limits
).cat.remove_unused_categories()


df.groupby(years)['value'].sum()
Out: 
date
(2000, 2005]     3
(2005, 2010]    18
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hey, ayhan! Thanks for an answer, looks great, let me check that!

Answer (score 2):

Just consider using math :-)

```
df.groupby(((df.date-1)//5+1)*5).value.sum().to_frame(name='value')
Out[185]: 
      value
date       
2005      3
2010     18
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick demonstration of how could you go about it. You make an index keeping track how many did you already processed:

```
years= [2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010]
data= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

fifths=0

for i in range(len(years)//5+1):
    print(years[fifths], sum(data[fifths:fifths+5]))
    fifths+=5
```

You will get as output:

```
2004 15
2009 13
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit more brute force and less elegant, but it shows some of the more basic pandas data frame building operations in a very clear and readable way. I think you will find ways to do this more elegantly over time.

```
import pandas as pd

# Prepare data set for dataframe
table = [['year','value']]

value = 0
for year in range(2004,2010,1):
    value += 1
    array = [year, value]
    table.append(array)

headers = table.pop(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=headers)

# Bucketize the data in a new dataframe
tableNew = [['year','value']]

sum = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    year = df.iloc[i]['year']
    value = df.iloc[i]['value']
    sum += value
    if (year % 5) == 0:
        tableNew.append([year, sum])
        sum = 0

while year % 5 != 0:
    i += 1
    year += 1
    value = 0
    sum += value
    if (year % 5) == 0:
        tableNew.append([year, sum])

newHeaders = tableNew.pop(0)
dfNew = pd.DataFrame(tableNew,columns=newHeaders)

print dfNew
```

Output:

```
   year  value
0  2005      3
1  2010     18
```